# codeigniter login controllers without database

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create a demo account. How can I create an easy login controllers that does not require a database?

This is my view.

```
  <div class="col-lg-12">
     <label class="control-label">
           Username / Email Address
      </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email_address" autofocus />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label class="control-label">
                Password:
          </label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
           <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
           <input type="submit" name="button" value="" class="btn-submit-student"/>
   </div>
```

Comment: Do you no need database?

Comment: for best practice you need database was well. or else just use with `==`

Comment: yes i no need database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this **(** As i understood your Question **)**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button']))
{
    $user = $_POST['email_address'];
    $pw = $_POST['password'];

    if($user =='my_username' and $pw=='My_Password')
    {
        //code if user name and Password matched
        echo 'Sucess';
    }
    else
    {
        //username and password Failed
        echo 'Failed';

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to store the password in plain text. You could easily `sha1()` / `hash('sha256', xxx)` this, if not salt it as well.

Comment: In your new edit, you're still storing the password in plain text. I can still see that the password is _My_Password_. You need to SHA1 it **outside** of the application. For example, `$u_pw = 'b44885d6c6d33c97192b69fa4d1c3acb53fa5a39'`. Then you need to hash the posted password, for example: `sha1($pw) == $u_pw` You do not need to hash the username.

Comment: Just a thought I would think for password hash and verify is use the php password_hash() http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and password_verfiy();  http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 nice, I didn't know about those methods!